# GWT add ids to the datagrids as a whole, its headers and rows

Tags: java, spring, gwt, frontend, uibinder

I'm struggling to give several ids to my data grids using gwt in order to ease the frontend testing using robotframework with selenium library.

How can I add an id to each header and row of the data grid or cell grid?

And to the whole datagrid?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

GWT has `DebugInfo` class which creates `dbg` attribute where you can add your custom information.
So you can do like this for example:

```
String dataGridId = "custom id for element";
someWidget.setAttribute(DebugInfo.getDebugIdAttribute(), dataGridId));
```

And your selenium can find element:

```
webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("*[dbg='" + dataGridId + "']"))
```

This way will work for whole data grid.
To search headers with selenium you can just compare text from header itself the same way

```
webDriver.findElement(By.anyMethod())).getText()
```

Actually you can `.getText()` from any `WebElement`